# If python list index is None

Tags: python, list, indexing, maze, nonetype

Basically I am making a [Maze Generator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyK_Q5rrcr4) in Python.

The program creates multiple `Cell` objects which once created, are pushed to a one dimensional list called `grid`, grid uses the function

```
def get_index(self, i, j, cols, rows):
    if i < 0 or j < 0 or i > cols-1 or j > rows-1
        return None
    return i + j * cols
```

to generate an index of itself and it's top, right, bottom, and left neighbours. I call this function for the 4 neighbours like this:

```
self.top = self.get_index(i, j-1, cols, rows)
self.right = self.get_index(i+1, j, cols, rows)
self.bottom = self.get_index(i, j+1, cols,       
self.left = self.get_index(i-1, j, cols, rows)
```

These 2 parts work. but as soon as I assign / check a cell which has a Null neighbour to the list like this

```
print(grid[self.top])
```

An exception is thrown because there is no neighbour! (None exception)

Is there any way of assigning a `None` value to a list of objects?

E.g. cell 0,0 has an index of 0, a top neighbour value of `None/-1/False etc.` A right value of 1, a bottom value of 10, and a left value of `None` aswell.

Then I want to check through the list and assign each cell its 4 neighbours.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I have since moved to a dictionary and it almost works. In the old approach `grid[]` would keep all the cell objects. Now `grid_dict{}` does. 
And it keeps the cell, i, and j. How do I use the value of i and j to act like a pointer to a cell object with that exact i and j? Once this works I will hope to do something like this to walk through neighbours

```
#use i, j of neighbour here to reference next cell
next() = neighbour()#random choice of top, right, bottom, left
next.visited = True
current = next()
```

Comment: Your problem is not assigning `None`, it's your looking at the `None` index in your list, which will raise an error. So you can check the index by assigning it a value, then verifying if it's not `None`

Comment: Why in the world would you represent a 2D maze with a 1D list?  Use either a list of lists (`grid[row][column]`), or a dictionary indexed by tuples (`grid[row, column]`).  With a 2D list you'd still need to check and avoid using out-of-bounds locations, with a dict you could actually have a `grid[None]` entry to represent all of the invalid neighbors.